# How to create a gamefield in qt with C++

Tags: c++, qt, chess

Hello im new to qt (C++) and i try to programm the Game Dame. My Problem is now that i dont know how to make the gamefield (same as chess gamefield) where i can put the game figures on and show possible movements when you click on a figure. I know that i can create an array by this way in C++:

```
int x, y;
int array[8][8];

for(y=0; y<8; y++)
{
    for(x=0; x<8; x++)
    {
        cout<<array[y][x];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Does anybody has an idea? I dont know which way is better (create an array or put in .png pictures and a button behind.

Comment: If you google search for "Qt chess board" you will find some code and good looking examples.

Comment: It's not clear what you want help with. You're asking which is better, an array or buttons, but they're not comparable. An array is not a visual element. You could combine them and use an array of buttons if you want. But how can we give you a good answer to this question? Please take a moment to to take our [tour]. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) page will be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [QGraphicsScene](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#details) is a very nice class that can be used to display sprites on a background.

Good overview here also : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html

It may be also possible to get click events to manage user interaction with the mouse.